# I want to implement material design in android for versions lower than lollipop

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, material-design, android-4.4-kitkat

I want to implement material design in android for versions lower than lollipop but i dont know whether it is possible? If it is possible then can someone help me on how to implement material design for kitkat and lower versions?

Please help providing some reference material to implement material design for kitkat or lower version.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very usefull [link](http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/android-design-support-library-codelab/en?utm_source=Android%20Weekly&utm_campaign=404735061d-Android_Weekly_159&utm_medium=email&utm_term=0_4eb677ad19-404735061d-337832373) about using the support library. I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Design Support library is what you are looking for!
Below link we help you get started..
http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html

Go through all the components introduced in the library and for the detailed know how you could google search each and every component as per need..Information/tutorials are easily available..

One more thing Stackoverflow is not the place for developers to ask any question without any research..there is google for that.
So, please first do some research on some topic,start writing code and when you are stuck somewhere then come here for help!!

SO community would be happy to help!

Happy Coding!! :)